# All files in webserver copy of index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am hosting a server on a Linux machine using Node.js, currently this is the file structure:

webServer

```
->node_modules (express, mysql2, path - only using express so far)
->client
-->index.hmtl 
-->style
--->style.css 
-->js
--->index.js
->server
-->server.js
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pootid</title>
  <link href=style/index.css rel=stylesheet>
  <script src=js/test.js></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <article>
    <p>Hi this is a webpage</p>
    <p>Hi this is another paragraph</p>
  </article>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

index.css:

body {
  background: red;
}
```

index.js:

```
'use strict'

window.addEventListener("load", boot);

async function boot() {
  test();
}

function test() {
  console.log("this is a test");
}
```

server.js:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.listen(8080);
//app.listen(80);

app.get('/api/test', test);

app.use('/', express.static('webpages'));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const top = path.resolve('.');
  const dir = `${top}/client/index.html`;
  res.sendFile(path.join(dir));
});

function test(req, res) {
  const testObject = {
    "test": "this is a test"
  };

  res.json(testObject);
}
```

Current css file in browser:

[image]

This seems to just be a copy of the html, I don't think this is to do with the network setup.

Comment: Your get catchall is sending out only your html file: `const dir = \`${top}/client/index.html\`;` There is no code to send out your css or other files

Comment: I thought the html was able to point to the js and css files using the tags in the head and I wouldn't have to explicitly send them out.

Comment: Would you please edit your post and write a question on it ?

Comment: the problem was just that I didn't rename the webpages directory to client on line 12 of the server